# Error de atributo al abrir una ventana con botones en PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

He definido dos ventanas, la primera que sería la principal y una subventana que contiene un botón, que llama a una función para hacer un gráfico a través de su método **'clicked'** para el evento respectivo.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# CLASS MAIN WINDOW 
# ¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯
class mainWindowInicial(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(mainWindowInicial,self).__init__(parent)
        loadUi('Gui/mainwindow.ui', self)
        self.actionData.triggered.connect(self.open_dataInput)      

#        self.x = graphics()

    # EVENTS ==================================================================
    def open_dataInput(self):
        DataInput(self).show()
        
#        self.draw()
        
def graphics():

    plt.plot((0,5),(0,5))
    plt.show()

class DataInput(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(DataInput,self).__init__(parent)
        loadUi('Gui/datawindow.ui', self)
        
#        self.draw() 
        self.pushButton_Graph.clicked.connect(self.draw)
        
        def draw():
            graphics()
        
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    widget = mainWindowInicial()
    widget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Mi problema es que al ejecutar me sale el siguiente error: DataInput' object has no attribute 'draw'.

Si alguien comprende PyQt5 un poco más, agradecería su ayuda, saludos cordiales.

[Archivos GUI](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AsVYG9GQfybKcyUvDAgS4WCapJg?e=Ld6ZgR)

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema ocurre porque nunca creas un puntero a la nueva ventana, de manera que cuando escribes `self.draw()` se lo estás pidiendo a tu main Window, y no a la nueva ventana.

Recomiendo que ese puntero lo guardes en la propia clase principal de tu programa, en la app, o en la main window así:

```
def open_dataInput(self):
    self.ventananueva = DataInput(self)  # Creamos la instancia, y la guardamos en un puntero/referencia llamado self.ventananueva
    self.ventananueva.show()  # Mostramos esa instancia/ventana
    self.ventananueva.draw()  # Usamos alguna función de ella
```

Esto deberia funcionar.

Comment: Gracias @Saelyth pero sigo teniendo el mismo problema, al final de mi pregunta he cargado los archivos.UI, ya que en mi código yo llamo a esos archivos directamente, no se si por ahí estoy haciendo algo mal ya que el boton de la clase 'DataInput', se conecta con la función 'graphics', que como observa no está definida dentro de una clase.

Comment: No estoy familiarizado con esa manera de cargar archivos ui. Yo siempre utilizo el comando `pyside2-uic -o` para generar archivos .py directamente.

Comment: Muchas gracias @Saelyth, aunque ya me dí cuenta el error, una simple identación, algo que literalmente no me había dado cuenta y que me ha tenido desde la mañana en esos apuros, agregaré una respuesta con esa parte.

Answer (score 0):

```
class DataInput(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(DataInput,self).__init__(parent)
        loadUi('Gui/datawindow.ui', self)
        
        self.pushButton_Graph.clicked.connect(self.draw)
        
    def draw(self):
        graphics()
```

Mucho cuidado con las identaciones, en lo personal, ese era mi problema, muchas gracias por las respuestas, saludos.